# How to prove the existence of limiting relative frequency (of frequentism) based on Kolmogorov axioms?

Tags: probability

I recently read Sheldon Ross' book [*A First Course in Probability*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/First-Course-Probability-International/dp/0136079091) and I have a question which comes from pg. 27, as stated in the title.

> ...
> $$P(E)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n(E)}{n}.$$
> That is, $P(E)$ is defined as the proportion of time that $E$ occurs. It is thus the limiting relative frequency of $E$.
> However, to assume that $\frac{n(E)}{n}$ will necessarily converge to some constant value seems to be an extraordinarily complicated assumption. In fact, **would it not be more reasonable to assume a set of simpler and more self-evident axioms about probability, and then attempt to prove that such a constant limiting frequency does in some sense exist?**

The axioms mentioned in the book are  [Kolmogorov axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms)

There seems to be no such proof in the book as far as I know. Does anyone know how to prove it?

Comment: Starting from the measure theoretic axiomatization proposed by Kolmogorov, and under assumption of independence, the limit of the proportion results from the law of large numbers.

Comment: "[the three Kolmogorov axioms]" I assume there was meant to be something here?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yeah, it make sense. In this book, law of large numbers is proved by Chebyshev's inequality under additional assumption that the random variables have a finite variance. That answers the question. I didn't realize it!